# In Jetbrains IDEs, is there a way to see changed rows since a specific commit, instead of working copy changes?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, webstorm

In Jetbrains IDEs, rows that reflect working copy changes are annotated in the left hand side in green/blue or a small triangle for removed rows. For example, see the green annotation in the following screenshot:

[image: Changes annotated in green in Intellij-ide]

Is there a way to configure the SVN integration that will allow showing changed rows annotations not for working copy changes, but for **all changes since a specific commit**? For example, all changes since 6 commits ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as of IntelliJ IDEA 14. There is an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24398) for this.